# react-router - handleLogin function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have the following structure for my React.js application using [React Router](https://dev.to/mychal/protected-routes-with-react-function-components-dh):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Landing from './components/Landing/Landing';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthProvider";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUser(true);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' handleLogin={handleLogin} 
        render={props => <Landing {...props} user={user.toString()} 
        handleLogin={handleLogin} />} />
        <Route exact path='/home' element={ <Home /> } />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I want to create a function called handleLogin which will invoke setUser and flip the user value to true when we click "Log In"

When I save it, It show  a blank page and on console it display

> Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This
> means it will render an  with a null value by default
> resulting in an "empty" page.

What's the easiest and right way to do?

Comment: What's in auth provider? You should export a function in it for set user.

Comment: Ignore Auth Provider. It was just for testing something else. Will you please explain how?

Comment: Using context api in react you can have your auth related context in the auth provider like [this blog](https://dev.to/finiam/predictable-react-authentication-with-the-context-api-g10)